# Объясните как работает следующий код (JS)

Tags: javascript

```
function random(){
var already_used = [];
return function() {
    var new_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    **for (var i = 0; i < already_used.length; i++) {
        if (already_used[i] == new_num) *{return}*
    };**

    parag.innerHTML += new_num+', ';
    already_used.push(new_num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `random()` — это функция, которая возвращает другую функцию, генерирующую случайное число. Также она содержит в себе массив `already_used`, в котором хранятся результаты предыдущих генераций для предотвращения повторений. Данная техника иллюстрирует использование [замыканий](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure).
- Результат вызова `random()` можно сохранить в переменную и вызывать как функцию. Ниже приведён пример использования такой возвращённой функции при помощи переменной `addRandom`: она привязана к щелчку кнопки как обработчик события.
- Каждый вызов `addRandom()` геренирует случайное число. Затем в цикле перебираются все прежние случайные числа, сохранённые в массиве. Если совпадение найдено, функция просто завершает работу. Это завершение и производится при помощи `{return}` — оно ничего не возвращает, просто обрывает выполнение функции. В этом случае нажатие на кнопку не производит никакого действия.
- Если совпадения нет, функция добавляет текущее случайное число в некий HTML элемент через запятую, а потом заносит число в массив для будущих проверок.

```js
function random(){
  var already_used = [];
  return function() {
    var new_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < already_used.length; i++) {
        if (already_used[i] == new_num) {return}
    };

    parag.innerHTML += new_num+', ';
    already_used.push(new_num);
  }
}

const addRandom = random();

mybutton.addEventListener('click', addRandom);
```

```html
<button id='mybutton'>Add random</button>

<div id='parag'></div>
```

Comment: Что делет {return} в отмеченном тексте. Что он выносит???

Comment: А что, нельзя было просто `random.already_used = [];` использовать, зачем обязательно замыкания?))

Comment: @Leonid, замыкание позволяет делать несколько разных `addRandom`, свойство в функции - становится общим для всех

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Использование замыканий становится более понятным. Получается, что модули в этом смысле не являются полным замещением замыканий, ведь они могут быть подключены единожды? Или я не прав?